# How do I put booleans into a mysql database with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, boolean, prepared-statement

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), the four variable types for `mysqli->bind_param` are

1. integer,
2. double,
3. string and
4. blob.

What is the best way to insert a boolean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MySQL doesn't really store booleans anyway, it's a trick.

The actual format is `TINYINT`, which is I guess `integer` for pdo.

You will have to convert true/false to 1/0, with [`intval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for example.

Comment: Is is possible to put a boolean php value directly into the prepared statement, or does it have to be converted? E.g. $test = false - can I insert test as a TINYINT or do I need to first convert $test to an int?

Comment: PHP converts booleans to nothing when you try to put it in a string, so it will not do 1/0 as expected. Just do $booleanvar?1:0 in your prepare call.